# axon transaction manager between command and query side

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cqrs, spring-transactions, axon

i have a spring boot maven multi module project with axon 4.4.2, the hierarchy of project is as below:

```
application
--core
--command-side
----command-side-axon
----command-side-rest
--query--side
----query-side-persistence
----query-side-rest
```

i have an example of create a new catalog as below, when i send a request from command-side-rest, it always returns an id as response, even if the query-side-persistence crashes and the data not is saved in the database. How can i handle transactions in this case ? I want when the  query-side-persistence crashes the event does not get saved in the event base and it throws an exception.

**command-side-rest**

```
@PostMapping
public String save(@RequestBody Catalog catalog) {
    return (String) commandGateway.sendAndWait(new CreateCatalogCommand(catalog));
}
```

**command-side-axon**

```
@CommandHandler
public void handle(CreateCatalogCommand cmd) {
    apply(new CatalogCreatedEvent(cmd.externalId, cmd.name));
}

@EventSourcingHandler
@Order(1)
public void on(CatalogCreatedEvent evt) {
    this.externalId = evt.externalId;
}
```

**query-side-persistence**

```
@EventHandler
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Order(2)
public void on(CatalogCreatedEvent event) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I can give you some information on the matter, concerning your main question:

> I want when the query-side-persistence crashes the event does not get saved in the event base and it throws an exception.

Well, that essentially means you **do not** want to use CQRS at all. What CQRS stands for is the segregation of your Command Model (e.g. the Aggregate handling the command and publishing the event) and the Query Models (e.g. the classes handling events which updates your models).

Segregating these two gives you the benefit that you can optimize your models for both scenarios. Added, the request to perform an operation, aka the command, is no longer influenced on whether the subsequent event actually can update a query model. On top of that, it shouldn't if you are doing CQRS! Having this exact segregation means you can recreate your Query Models *whenever* you need, entirely separated from performing the commands.

Thus essentially, your Event Store because the single model you can base *all* models from, independent from another. This is why using events when going for CQRS works so nicely with Event Sourcing (which states to recreate your Command Model based on the events *it* has published).

So, my recommendation? I would embrace the fact that if event handling to update your query model fails, that the event still has happened. It essentially didn't change the fact your system has made the decision to publish that event, so let it be so.

If you do want to have your Command Model and Query Model in a single transaction, you could still achieve this by *only* using the `SubscribingEventProcessor` in Axon. Again though, I would discuss with your team/business whether that is really what you need.
Check out some of the posts on the "learning" [page](https://axoniq.io/resources/architectural-concepts) of AxonIQ to have a feel why CQRS, DDD and Event Sourcing can be beneficial for you.

Hope this sheds some light on the situation Aymen!